# Expected Value of neural network output

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm attempting to find a closed form expected value of a particularly messy expression involving dot products of multiple neural network outputs.

A sub-problem of this is to consider just a single feed-forward network.

---

Consider the feed-forward neural network with weight matrices $W_1 \in \mathbb{R^{k_2 \times k_1}}$, $W_2\in \mathbb{R^{k_3 \times k_2}}$, and input $x\in \mathbb{R^{k_1}}$. Treat each component of these as iid random variables normally distributed with the following means, $\mu_{W_1}, \mu_{W_2}, \mu_{x}$ and variances, $\sigma_{W_1}, \sigma_{W_2}, \sigma_{x}$, respectably. E.g. $[W_1]_{i,j} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{W_1},\sigma_{W_1})$.

The neural network output would be

$$ o(W_1,W_2,x) := g(W_2 g(W_1x))$$

where $g$ is the relu function.

What then would be its expected value?

$$ E[g(W_2 g(W_1x))]$$

I know this can fairly easily be calculated through Monte Carlo methods, but is it possible to come up with a closed-form expression or a closed-form approximation?

Comment: What kind of neural network is this? Also, why would you want to calculate an expected value of the random untrained neural network?

Comment: @BDN A feedforward network. Yes an untrained one.

Comment: It would help if you'd explain the concrete problem. If the variances are small then you can replace the $\max$ function by a smooth approximation and use the partial derivatives to estimate the variance. If the variance is large, I would try to estimate $|o(x)-o(x+a)|$ for different $x,a$

Comment: The concrete problem is to get a closed-form expression, in terms of the means and variances of the distributions, of the expected value of the network output. I can easily obtain the actual expected value by running a monte carlo sim, but I would like to be able to derive it theoretically.

Comment: If relu needs to be replaced by a smooth approximation of relu, that's fine. Or if there is some sort of approximation technique similar to Taylor series, that is fine too.